# Exception not tested with phpUnit?

Tags: php, unit-testing, zend-framework, phpunit

I'm writing some unit test with phpUnit to test a Zend Framework application and I've got some issues with testing an exception in the changePassword function. The test doesn't fail, but in the coverage tool which generates html the "throw new Exception($tr->translate('userOldPasswordIncorrect'));" line isn't tested.

```
public function changePassword(array $data, $id)
{
    $user = $this->_em->find('Entities\User', (int) $id);

    $oldPassword = sha1(self::$_salt . $data['oldPassword']);
    if ($user->getPassword() !== $oldPassword) {
        $tr = PC_Translate_MySQL::getInstance();
        throw new Exception($tr->translate('userOldPasswordIncorrect'));
    }

    $user->setPassword(sha1(self::$_salt . $data['password']));

    $this->_em->persist($user);
    $this->_em->flush();
}
```

The unit test which should test the exception:

```
/**
 * @depends testFindByAuth
 * @expectedException Exception
 */
public function testChangePasswordWrongOldPassword()
{
    $this->_dummyUser = $this->_user->findByAuth($this->_dummyEmail, $this->_dummyPassword, $this->_reseller);

    // Try to change the password with a wrong oldPassword
    $data['oldPassword'] = 'wrongOldPassword';
    $data['password'] = $this->_dummyNewPassword;

    $this->_user->changePassword($data, $this->_dummyUser->getId());
}
```

I'll hope somebody can tell me what I'm doing wrong.

**Update**

The problem was inside the PC_Translate_MySQL::getInstance() method. There was thrown an exception. And as I was testing on getting a general exception this ofcourse passed. Solution don't use a general Exception in the changePassword method.

Comment: is testFindByAuth passing? If not, depends wont even let testChangePasswordWrongOldPassword run.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

My guess?  There's an exception being thrown from `PC_Translate_MySQL::getInstance()`...

That's the trouble with using a single `Exception`.  It makes it tougher to check what exception was thrown.  I'd suggest changing the `changePassword` method to throw a different exception.  Perhaps a `InvalidArgumentException`, or a `RuntimeException`.  And then test for that one.

Personally, I use custom exceptions all the time for this reason.

```
try {
} catch (DatabaseQueryException $e) {
    // Handle database error
} catch (DatabaseConnectionException $e) {
    // We never even connected...
} catch (InvalidArgumentException $e) {
    //...
}
```

I, as a rule, never use `catch (Exception $e)` for that very reason.  You never know what exception you caught.  (I do have a custom exception handler defined, so I don't fatal if the application doesn't catch.  Instead it shows a 500 error and logs the exception)...

Comment: This has to be it. But then the code coverage report would show which exception actually got hit...

Comment: It would?  Sure it would increment the throw exception, but if like me you have a bunch of tests, will you notice 240 visits to the exception instead of 239?  AFAIK, the coverage report (HTML or XML) doesn't show the actual exception that was thrown, only what lines were covered (hence why the OP knew to ask the question)...

Comment: There was an exception indeed. When unit testing there is no $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME']; Thx!